# How to unlock a locked site collection in C#?

Tags: 2013, development

I have a locked site collection (set to "no access" in Central Administration).

I can unlock / lock this site collection easily with PowerShell:

```
Set-SPSite -identity "<url>" –LockState Unlock
```

It is also documented fairly well: [Manage the lock status for site collections in SharePoint Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sites/manage-the-lock-status-for-site-collections).

My problem is that I cannot unlock the site from any SSOM code. When doing `SPSite.ReadOnly = false` I get a COM-Exception saying the site is currently locked and I don't have access. Of course I tried doing this with an elevated site.

After a lot of digging I found that somewhere along the line [`Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.CurrentUserIsAdministrator`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spfarm.currentuserisadministrator?view=sharepoint-server) is being called and that checks whether the current process (W3WP) is allowed to do administration. I suppose only the central administration process is allowed to do certain tasks (and PowerShell / STSADM).

My question is: For a site with NoAccess (`Set-SPSite -identity "<url>" –LockState NoAccess`) - how do I unlock it from code without using STSADM or PowerShell?

Comment: Have a look into `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges` and try that.

Comment: of course I did this elevated. I also fiddled around with some advanced impersonation.

Comment: did you try to run your code under Farm account?

Comment: yes of course, local dev account is farm admin and I also impersonated other accounts. I didn't try the SYSTEM account (setupuser) - maybe that's a trick. It'd help if someone were to try setting and unsetting the lockstate via C#